# change right and left icon "switch"

Tags: jquery, css

need when I click on the icon to the right and click the left again

to do this, I wrote a style css `"shareleft"` & `"shareright"`

I use jQuery code to change the icon style

```
   $(".share").click(function () {
    $(".share > ul").slideToggle();
    $(".share").toggleClass("shareleft shareright");
   })
```

but many of the icons on a page

clicking on one of them, all the icons are switched

but I want only the icon `"click on"` to be changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery click handler actually provides you with the exact element (see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/click/). You can use `e.target` or `this` to get the clicked element:

```
$(".share").click(function (e) {
    var $el = $(this); // Could also use $(e.target);
    $el.children("ul").slideToggle();
    $el.toggleClass("shareleft shareright");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the selectors in your function are collecting all elements that are child `ul`s of a `.share` element along with all elements with the class of `.share`.

Inside your function you have:

```
$(".share > ul").slideToggle();
$(".share").toggleClass("shareleft shareright");
```

`$(".share > ul")` is selecting all `ul`s that are a child of a `.share` element and `$(".share")` is selecting all elements with the `.share` class applied.

Use the keyword `this` to refer to the element that was clicked.

```
$(".share").click(function(e) {
    var $this - $(this);
    $this.children("ul").slideToggle();
    $this.toggleClass("shareleft shareright");
});
```

If you're wondering why there is a `$` at the beginning of the variable name that is because jQuery is represented by the `$` and by convention placing the `$` at the beginning of the variable name tells us that this variable is a jQuery object.